# Is it obligatory to educate daughters?

Tags: fiqh, sunni

Is it obligatory to educate one’s daughter. I am asking this because many people argue that Islam is discriminating towards women. Can anyone give me a Hadith about it?

Comment: Please refrain from adding irrelevant tags to your questions.

Comment: @goldPseudo how are they irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Education of children has never been requested in Islam.
Education means to make the children fit for life and let them learn what is needed therefore.
It includes spiritual/religious education and the skills needed for a good life.

Education of children off course includes education of girls.  This has never been put in question; a hadith says that it's good (mustahab) to educate also a slave girl:

Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "He who has a slave-girl and educates and treats her nicely and then manumits and marries her, will get a double reward."

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2544
https://sunnah.com/bukhari:97
and several parallels.

There's no particular hadith on education of daughters. This is due to the fact that this was taken for granted for if it is good to educate a slave girl it has certainly not been considered unnecessary for the own daughters.

The skills needed today differ from the skills needed in the past, and they differ from one society to another.

You are probably asking about schooling and studying.
We must see that such education was not common for boys in the times of the prophet. Adequate education for boys and girls is different today but it is still good.